# Implicit Intent or Explicit Intent in Android

Tags: android-intent, implicit, explicit

This intent :

Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.youtube");

is Implicit or Explicit Intent ?

Answer (score 0):

This is an Explicit Intent.

> Explicit intents specify which application will satisfy the intent, by supplying either the target app's package name or a fully-qualified component class name.

[More here on Android docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#Types)